# passing exe to non-admin user outside network to install software

Tags: windows, batch-file, runas, impersonation, autoit

I'm in a dead end now and need your help. I tried everything I could find on the web, but didn't succeed.

**I have hundreds of *non-admin* domain users working on their Windows 10 laptops *outside* our network with *no* VPN connection to the domain.**

**I need to pass them a file so they can install a small piece of software.**

In the old days, we scripted the function *RunAs* in **AutoIt**, compiled it (with the hard coded credentials inside) and shared the file with the outside users. They just needed to run it.
Not a perfect solution, nor the safest, but it worked for emergencies.

But now those days are gone, with UAC and the need for elevation, even with logged-on admins.

**is there any way to get the software installed by a non-admin user, not in contact with the DCs, with just running a local script or exe or even a msi?**

Like passing admin credentials encrypted or compiled on a script, or even **sign** the exe or msi file on the domain so that Windows OS can trust it and accept the install even if not in contact with it?

I tried **all** the AutoIt forums' suggestions, tried the *not-so-old* **schtasks** workaround, RunAs alternatives, etc, but it all needs elevation even when run with admin credentials.

There must be a safe way to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html

Try this with the companion program RunElevated.

Comment: Thank Khidir, I'll give it a try..

Comment: It works, @Khidir O.
`RunAsSpc.exe /program:"runelevated.exe" /executein:"c:\somefolder" /param:"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec /i myprogram.msi /qn /li myprogram.log" /user:"_administrator_name_" /password:"_password_in_here_" `. 
**You still get prompted by UAC**, but you just need to say "**Yes**" and the software is only free for **private use**.